# FQL permission troubles for certain users

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm writing an App where users can post some of their photos. I'm therefor saving the object_ids of the photos and try to show them to another user. In most cases it works fine, but in some cases None of the photos are showed or just some of them are.

FQL-query is the following:

```
SELECT object_id, images, src FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (1234, 5678,9012) ORDER BY object_id
```

The access token of the user of the requested photos is still valid. They were both signed in using my app. 
I don't get any error back, just an empty array.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Most likely the user that posted the photo via your app has set the privacy for posts made via your app so that your other user is not allowed to see them.

Comment: Yes, thats it. The user wants to share a photo which has the privacy only for friends. Is it possible to give my application somehow permissions for that picture?

Comment: The user has set the privacy to "friends only" for a reason - so why do you think your app should __undermine__ that to show his content to other users?

Comment: Yes, he chose it for Facebook itself. But in the app he wants to share that picture with the other app users.

Comment: Well then save the photo on your own server as well, so you can show it to other users of your app.

Comment: Yes, I guess thats the only way...